# Java conventions about primitive types

Tags: java, boolean, conventions, primitive-types

What are the Java conventions on primitive types? Should I be documenting each primitive type if I name it properly?

```
/**
 * This is the variable that handles whether or not a person has turned on a light.
 */
private boolean toggleLight = false;
```

That just seems to me like it's absolute overkill, if anyone has a source or just plain previous knowledge then that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the verbosity doesn't have much to do with the type per se, but rather with the long-windedness of "This is the variable that handles..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think more than anything it depends on the team you are working in, different companies and even projects have different "standards".  I personally don't bother to comment every variable, especially as variables tend to be private.  If a variable is public then I will comment it so it appears in my Javadoc.

Same goes for methods, if it's a private method I don't bother commenting if it's obvious, I also don't comment setters and getters, only methods with logic in.

As I said though, it generally depends on the team within which you are coding.

Answer (score 2):

This got nothing to do with primitive types. You give a fine example yourself: the name `toggleLight` is not self-explanatory. Add a comment, better yet, change the name.

Another example I love is `float weight` – well, what unit is this weight in? Is it even weight as in *mass*, or rather weight as in *importance*.

Comment: I understand what you mean by this, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

This got nothing to do with java, it should be company specific not programign language spicific. If your team decides to document every variable this would be the case. In general its good to document each methode, specially public ones from hich the IDE shows the documentation while working with them, some companies decide to document private methods too, which could be necessary specially if the methode is big and the name isnt enough to describe what the methode does.

Its important to consider the documentation format as there are lots of documentation generating tools which read specific patrts pf the documentation according to XML Tags.

Comment: Well you just edited your answer, before you edited (when I commented) it was a one liner not answering the question in the slightest.

Comment: As a point to your statement " if the methode is big and the name isnt enough to describe what the methode does", if the method really is that big it is probably in need of refactoring into smaller parts.

Comment: even then it was an answer, saying thhat documentation isnt programmign language specific but team desicion is actually a full answer.

Comment: right but refactoring isnt the main issue here so im not gona go there in my answer

Comment: @JonTaylor by the way your answer is nothing more than that one liner answer and the rest is just an opinion issue isnt it.

Comment: Not "going there" is often the problem, bringing refactoring of code into question is something that needs to be done more often, too often do I see cumbersome methods that are overly complex and people try and offset this by leaving a long programmers comment which invariably does not help.  As for my answer, it details why and yes, does continue to give an opinion, often answers are formed partially of opinions.  As for your original answer it was a valid answer but lacked any detail, hence why it really should have been a comment.